# Switch between two locations

Tags: python, constraints, drivers

I have an object that I wanted to only be limited to two possible locations, ex: X=0 OR X=1... so if the object is on X=0 and I move it forwards, it jumps to X=1, and if X=1 and I move it backwards, it jumps to X=0.

Using the Limit Location constraint only allows me to limit the object location inside a range (if min=0 and max=1, location can be 0.5, 0.3, 0.8 etc).

Is there any way to do it, even if using drivers and python expressions (maybe using an OR logic gate)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity and avoiding the use of extra information:

You can check 'use self' which allows to get data from the object directly.

Using 'self' calculates the expression during the move, but keeps the current value (so that no circular dependencies) and finally apply the expression.

So for instance if the expression is:

```
(self.location[0] <= 0.5) * 0 + (self.location[0] > 0.5) * 1
```

you obtain:

[image]

*Edit*: of course in this case, the expression can be shorten to:

```
self.location[0] > 0.5
```

*Edit2*: following the comment of @DuaneDibbley, for your information.

A Python boolean expression can be True or False and True is numerically equal to 1, False is numerically equal to 0.

So you can use them as numerical values.

Comment: Explaining that booleans are actually represented by integers might be useful, as the OP mentioned in a reply to my comment to his own answer that he's pretty new to Python.

Comment: @batFINGER, sure! This was to give a way to assign values different to 0 and 1

Comment: Yep read on and saw that (deleted comment).  This only works if the cube is moved  more than 0.5 forward or back from 0 or 1, anything less wont give the behaviour requested in question.

Comment: @batFINGER, see what you and agree

Comment: @lemon let me see if I understood the expression: if the self location is greater than 0.5 then the expression is True, therefore equal  to 1? If less then it is False and equal to 0? Testing here I see that to increase the distance you then have to multiply the final value, so instead of *1, you use *2, etc... correct?

Comment: @batFinger, it is not instantaneous movement I agree, and there's the limitation that you are better using always the middle point, ex: if you are multiplying by 3 to move 3 units, then the best is use ">1.5" (half). Otherwise you would have to move the mouse a lot to go back from final location to initial location. Anyway it is still the most elegant solution if the distance you want to move is not too great, and you don't care to have to move a mouse a little (which in my case I don't). And one main advantage of lemon's solution is that you can parent it and move/scale it and it still works.

Comment: @Arkhangels, yes (0.2 < 0.5) = True = 1. If you want it between 1 and 2, that could be (x <= 1.5) * 1 + (x > 1.5) * 2, to be finally either 1 or 2. But I agree, as batFINGER said, that the alternate effect is not instant

Comment: @Arkhangels, just an idea but I don't know if it fits your need. Using the same principle on another object (say obj2), with a smaller range can be used to drive this object (say obj1) between 0 and 1. For instance, we apply the formula to obj2 between 0 and 0.1, then you should report these values to obj1, via x(obj1) = 10 * x(obj2)

Comment: @lemon, your original solution already fit my needs! :)... I was looking for some way to create a simple on/off switch controlled directly on the viewport. Now with your's or my own solution it's possible to create drivers for the initial/final locations and not worry about the button being somewhere in the middle between on/off.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Here is a quick setup in Animation Nodes, I think either using Snap or just limit between 2 values using Switch node. Depending on condition.

Comment: Really cool, thanks!!! That Switch node is so useful I cannot believe!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just managed to do the switch positions thing on the viewport (which is what I wanted), using drivers and a scripted expression (avoiding a dependency cycle which is the worst problem).

The secret was using a driver on Delta Transforms instead of regular transforms, because if you use a driver on the regular transforms (ex: X-Location), Blender doesn't let you move the object at all on the viewport, but changing Delta values still lets you move the object on the viewport so we can use any local location changes to trigger the driver.

The final driver uses the Local Location of the object (var), and also the Data Path of it's own Delta Location(var2).
The scripted expression is as follows:

1 if (var>0 and var!=0 and var2!=1) else 0 if (var<1 and var!=1) else 1

The logic of the expression is:

> The initial Delta Location is Value1 which is X=0
>
> The final Delta Location is Value2 which is X=1
>
> So if the cube Local Location(var) is anything but Value1, which it is
>   as soon as I move it a little bit and it leaves 0, then the cube Delta Location must be changed to Value2, so the cube jumps to X=1.
>
> Since the first IF part of the expression also determines that the Delta Location must not be exactly Value2 (var2!=1), and now it is, then the IF becomes invalid and the Else part happens, so when I try to move the cube from X=1 back to zero it then checks if the Local Location is less than Value2
>   and also not exactly Value2 meaning that it just left X=1. If yes, then the cube's Delta Location must be changed to Value1,
>   so the cube jumps to X=0, back to the start.
>
> The last Else is unnecessary because it never happens, but I must use it for the expression to be valid.

I also added a limit location constraint to keep the cube inside the 0-1 range.

Here is an image:
[image]

And it working:

[image]

Comment: This is good, but why the `var>0 and var!=0` and the `var<1 and var!=1`? If var is greater than 0, it is by definition not equal to zero, and if it less than one it is by definition not equal to 1. This seems redundant to me, and I'm curious about whether you actually tried without it.

Comment: You are probably right... I'm pretty new to python programming, and I kept adding conditions to see if it would work, and as soon as it did I left it afraid of ruining it haha... PS: I just checked and you are correct, it is redundant, but curiously If I left the "!=" instead of the greater/less sign it worked but glitched a little... while leaving only the greater/less signs worked flawlessly

Comment: Oh and to explain my train of thought when I was making it, I wanted to guarantee that the if or else would NOT work if the value was exactly 1 (for example), but would FOR SURE work if the value was anything BUT 1 you know? The redundancy was not really necessary in the end :/

Comment: @Arkhangels, for your information, you can also check 'use self' and set '(self.location[0] <= 0.5) * 0 + (self.location[0] > 0.5)' as expression (with no other variables needed)... I think I add an answer about that because this is to avoid circular dependencies